# google speech api forbidden

Tags: python, speech-recognition, google-speech-api

Hey Guys I am working on google speech api using python speech recognition model. I have tried using the default api along with them and it works. But when I try to use it along with my api. I am getting the following error:

> Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service;
>   recognition request failed: Forbidden

And this is my code

```
import speech_recognition as sr
from os import path
AUDIO_FILE = path.join(path.dirname(path.realpath(__file__)), "file.wav")

r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.AudioFile(AUDIO_FILE) as source:
    audio = r.record(source) # read the entire audio file
try:
# for testing purposes, we're just using the default API key
# to use another API key, use `r.recognize_google(audio, key="GOOGLE_SPEECH_RECOGNITION_API_KEY")`
# instead of `r.recognize_google(audio)`
print("Google Speech Recognition thinks you said " + r.recognize_google(audio, key="AIzaSyAqwPcs_F6cyNltsrZPGRQKRFakDX3d85"))
except sr.UnknownValueError:
   print("Google Speech Recognition could not understand audio")
except sr.RequestError as e:
   print("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition   service; {0}".format(e))
```

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Add a `raise` below the last `print` to see the real error message.

Comment: Be careful giving away your key in your code snippet, if that is a secret key.

Comment: I see that your code is copied from [here](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/issues/132) (2 last comments). Are you sure you are not doing the same mistake as him?

Comment: So I'am supposed to use my service account key instead of my api?

Comment: I have tried anything and everything i could get my hands on but its still not working i used the raise command and got a url error `URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 32] Broken pipe>`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest first set your credentials as a local variable:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='/home/user/Documents/your_credentials.json'
```

Details here: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started

Then this could help for long .wav transcripts: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/async-recognize?hl=es

The language is defined by 'en-US' for example for english US. See here the complete list https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/languages?hl=es

Answer (score 0):

notice that when you use googles speech recognition API without a key, the speech recognition module will use a default key. However Google can reject that request at any time. In that case you will get the error `recognition request failed: Forbidden`. This will also happen if you use a wrong key.
Quote from the module at `__init__.py` at line 810:

> Performs speech recognition on `audio_data` (an `AudioData`
> instance), using the Google Speech Recognition API. The Google Speech
> Recognition API key is specified by `key`. If not specified, it uses
> a generic key that works out of the box. This should generally be used
> for personal or testing purposes only, as it **may be revoked by
> Google at any time**. To obtain your own API key, simply following the
> steps on the `API Keys <http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/api-keys>`__ page at the
> Chromium Developers site. In the Google Developers Console, Google
> Speech Recognition is listed as "Speech API".

Just either get yourself a key or if you really don't want to then use the inbuilt `recognize_sphynx(audio)` or the snowboy.